# When I use QtGui.QIntValidator() it set Max length of text to 10 integers?

Tags: python, validation, user-interface, pyqt5

I  am using PyQt5 to build a desktop application , however, I have some QlineEdit fields that I want to them to accept integers only .when I used QtGui.QIntValidator() , I found that the maximum number of integers I can enter is 10 even  I am not using setMaxLength() function

After googling , I found no clue about this issue

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 40, 181, 31))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.intInputValidation=QtGui.QIntValidator()
        self.lineEdit.setValidator(self.intInputValidation)


        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3):

> QRegExp Class
>
> The QRegExp class provides pattern matching using regular expressions

---

> QRegExpValidator Class
>
> The QRegExpValidator class is used to check a string against a regular expression.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 40, 181, 31))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
    
#        self.intInputValidation = QtGui.QIntValidator()
#        self.lineEdit.setValidator(self.intInputValidation)

        rx  = QtCore.QRegExp("[0-9]{30}")                           # +++    
        val = QtGui.QRegExpValidator(rx)                            # +++   
        self.lineEdit.setValidator(val)                             # +++   
        
        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qintvalidator.html#top-prop

> top : int
> This property holds the validator's highest acceptable value
>
> By default, this property's value is derived from the highest signed integer available (typically 2147483647).

Try to increase it with `setTop(int)`.

Comment: I see , it didn't work with me . is there any other work around to make this validation possible ?

Comment: Not understand what's your issue here exactly?

Comment: @ipaleka The issue is that the highest signed integer available is `2147483647`. If you try to set a value greater than that, PyQt will raise an OverflowError. Of course, *Python* supports larger integers than that, but PyQt cannot force Qt to do likewise - hence the pre-emptive error.